# How to copy contents of list items from one list to another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to copy the contents of each `<li>` in a list to a corresponding `<li>` in another list. So the first item from #list1 would go into the first item of #list2. The third item of #list1 would go into the third item of #list2.

Here is my html:

```
<ul id="list1">
    <li>List Item 1</li>
    <li>List Item 2</li>
    <li>List Item 3</li>
    <li>List Item 4</li>    
    <li>List Item 5</li>
    <li>List Item 6</li>
    <li>List Item 7</li>        
</ul>


<ul id="list2">
    <li class="item yes">COPY GOES HERE</li>
    <li class="item yes">COPY GOES HERE</li>
    <li class="item yes">COPY GOES HERE</li>
    <li class="item">COPY GOES HERE</li>
    <li class="item">COPY GOES HERE</li>
    <li class="item">COPY GOES HERE</li>            
</ul>
```

I tried the following, but it copies the whole `<li>` elements, and I only want to copy the text *inside* each `<li>`:

```
$(newList).html($(oldlist).html());
```

Then I tried this, but couldn't get it to work:

```
var headings = '';
    
$("#list1 li").each(function(idx, li) {
        headings = $(li).html();
});
    
  
$("#list2 li").each(function(idx, li) {
       var items = $(li).html();
    
       $( items ).html( headings );
       
});
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to do it with below code

```js
const list1 = document.querySelectorAll('#list1 li'),
      list2 = document.querySelectorAll('.list2');

list2.forEach((list) => {
  const newList = list.querySelectorAll('li');
  list1.forEach((li, index) => newList[index] ? newList[index].textContent = li.textContent : '');  
})
```

```html
<ul id="list1">
    <li>List Item 1</li>
    <li>List Item 2</li>
    <li>List Item 3</li>
    <li>List Item 4</li>    
    <li>List Item 5</li>
    <li>List Item 6</li>
    <li>List Item 7</li>        
</ul>


<ul class="list2">
    <li class="item yes">COPY GOES HERE</li>
    <li class="item yes">COPY GOES HERE</li>
    <li class="item yes">COPY GOES HERE</li>
    <li class="item">COPY GOES HERE</li>
    <li class="item">COPY GOES HERE</li>
    <li class="item">COPY GOES HERE</li>            
</ul>

<ul class="list2">
    <li class="item yes">COPY GOES HERE</li>
    <li class="item yes">COPY GOES HERE</li>
    <li class="item yes">COPY GOES HERE</li>
    <li class="item">COPY GOES HERE</li>
    <li class="item">COPY GOES HERE</li>
    <li class="item">COPY GOES HERE</li>
    <li class="item">COPY GOES HERE</li>   
</ul>
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! But, I just noticed it's only doing it for the first list. I simplified my example, but in reality, #list2 is actually a class .list2 that appears several times on the page. Can I modify this to do this foreach .list2? (There is only one #list1).

Comment: @LBF I will update my answers. so there are many .list2 ul. correct?

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much. I tried adding a forEach but I was doing it in the wrong spot. I now understand how I was mixing it up.